# How to build-compile a .c file

Tags: debian, compiling, character-encoding, dynamic-linking

I have little experience with LINUX . I am using Debian.
It has a library glibc which has several useful programs.
iconv is the program that i want to use to do several charset conversions...
However i want to create my charset to use it at a really old from 1978 dot matrix  heavy duty printer which has a custom charset for my language...  Capital latin /greek only 7 bit
So i should write my own module for iconv...
I found how to configure it and make it but i dont know how to do the compilation.. from source .c file to .so file....
If there is no solution i will try to build from source the libc libray and copy the .so file that it should generate (think so)...

Comment: It's not so clear here. You want to know how to use gcc to compile C program?

Comment: yes.. i want to compile it into a .so so that it can be used/executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search led me to [this HOWTO](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html). I have no experience with this, but your command will look similar like this:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,your_soname -o library_name file_list library_list
```

Comment: Where `you_soname` should be the name of your charset, and `library_name` should be that name followed by `.so`.